# VehicleRoutingAlgorithmBuilder class is not there in Jsprit 1.7-RC1

Tags: jsprit

VehicleRoutingAlgorithmBuilder class is not present in release 1.7-RC1 , That's why I am unable to use code :

```
VehicleRoutingAlgorithmBuilder vraBuilder = new VehicleRoutingAlgorithmBuilder(vrp, "algorithmConfig_solomon.xml");
    vraBuilder.addCoreConstraints();
    vraBuilder.setNuOfThreads(4);
    VehicleRoutingAlgorithm vra = vraBuilder.build();
```

Is there any other way to re-write the above code?

Comment: it is removed in this commit: https://github.com/graphhopper/jsprit/commit/667db19f326d5aea2d30a0174c125508f66ed0fd and you can check out jspirt-io: https://github.com/graphhopper/jsprit/tree/master/jsprit-io/src/main/java/com/graphhopper/jsprit/io/algorithm

Comment: Thanks @HeHuang I have checked the jsprit-io , but VehicleRoutingAlgorithmBuilder is not there.